# How to pass arguments to Azure Custom Script Extension using the portal?

Tags: azure, azureportal

I want to use the Azure Custom Script Extension and pass arguments to my script:

[image]

The help bubble is not too helpful, and I can't find any examples **using the portal**.
I need a sample parameters section for my main script and an arguments sample to use in the portal. Preferably for at least two parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In our local environment, We have created a sample custom script to install **"Greenshot.exe"** in our virtual machine.

In our custom script Before installing the software, it will create a registry key & a folder and both will be APPX.

We have uploaded the Greenshot.exe file to the storage account & we have passed the blob uri as an argument for `Invoke-web request` in our custom script

**Here is the sample script that we have used:**

```
    New-Item -path "HKLM:\Software\AppX"
 Mkdir C:\AppX
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://strgdiagxx.blob.core.windows.net/cont1/Greenshot-INSTALLER-1.2.10.6.exe" -OutFile "C:\AppX\greenshot.exe"

C:\AppX\Greenshot.exe /lang=english /verysilent
Write-Output $(Get-Date) > C:\Temp\date.txt
$param=$Args[0]
Write-Output $($param)> C:\Temp\param.txt
```

These are the arguments that were passed through portal UI "tester1","tester2". All the arguments that were getting passed through portal UI are getting appended to Args[0].

we can not pass variables through these optional arguments.

**Here is the sample output for reference:**

[image]

[image]

**Note:**

As per the  Current [Azure  Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows#virtual-machine-scale-sets), If you deploy the Custom Script Extension from the Azure portal, you don't have control over the expiration of the SAS token for accessing the script in your storage account.

It is recommended to you use the [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.Compute/Add-azVmssExtension?view=azps-7.0.0), the  [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vmss/extension), or an Azure Resource Manager template when you deploy the Custom Script Extension on a virtual machine scale set.